# SQL query that fetches results based on parent results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains posts. Said table has few important fields, I'd like to use for filtering, mainly

**id**, **thread** and **bump**.

ID, is, well, the id. I'd like to sort from newest, but I'm using the timestamp for that (bump).

Thread is the thread number. If a post IS a thread, then thread IS null.

Bump is a timestamp, of when a thread was updated OR when a post was made.

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts_boardname` WHERE `thread` IS NULL ORDER BY `bump` DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

So take 10 threads and sort them by update timestamp. Simple, right? It workst just fine, yet since I also want to grab 3 last responses to each thread, I'd also like to have 3 posts, for each `thread`, so I came up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts_boardname` AS thr WHERE `thread` IS NULL OR (SELECT * FROM `posts_boardname` WHERE `thread` = thr.id ORDER BY `bump` DESC LIMIT 3) ORDER BY `bump` DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

But I get an error:
`Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Is what I'm trying to do even possible in MySQL? I've been unable to find any satisfying answers or solutions to this problem.

Sample data:

```
ID | Thread | Comment   | Timestamp | Bump
-- | ------ | --------- | --------- | ----
1  | NULL   | Thread #1 | 15        | 60
2  | NULL   | Thread #2 | 20        | 20
3  | 1      | ComTT #1  | 30        | 30
4  | NULL   | Thread #3 | 33        | 33
5  | 1      | ComTT #1-2| 60        | 60
6  | NULL   | Thread #4 | 65        | 65
```

Let's say I want to grab 3 lastest threads + 1 last response for each thread, if there are any, so my results would be:

```
ID | Thread | Comment   | Timestamp | Bump
-- | ------ | --------- | --------- | ----
6  | NULL   | Thread #4 | 65        | 65
1  | NULL   | Thread #1 | 15        | 60
5  | 1      | ComTT #1-2| 60        | 60
4  | NULL   | Thread #3 | 33        | 33
```

I tried doing the following with UNION, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM `posts_boardname` as thread 
 WHERE `threads` IS NULL 
 ORDER BY `bump` 
 DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) 
UNION 
(SELECT * 
 FROM `posts_boardname` as posts 
 WHERE `threads` = thread.id 
 ORDER BY `bump` DESC LIMIT 3)
```

Error: `#1054 Unknown column thread.id in where clausule`

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added.

Comment: Do two queries, one for the threads and one for the posts. Combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar Creating sample data for a question like this is annoying, that's why I shortened the example. A good solution should work for both cases regardless as long as you change how many results I'd want.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried using `UNION` but it doesn't seem to quite work, could you maybe take a look? I've added it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: The two queries in a union can't refer to each other. That only works in a join.

Comment: @Barmar so then it's impossible to achieve what I was trying to do with a single query?

Comment: I just misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. I thought the list of threads and list of 3 post in each thread were independent queries.

Comment: You need a join. Write a query that returns 10 threads, join it with a query that returns 3 posts from each thread. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group for how to get N rows per thread.